# Problem with Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

Using the command "make apps", I wanna generate two executables: main_test.exe and main_app2.exe.
For some reason, the command to generate main_test.exe is more is less completley ignored when
I run the makefile. Finally, I end up with a main_app.exe and main_app2.exe file but there is no
main_test.exe file produced. Anyone an idea why objcopy command is ignored in my makefile?

```
# make apps to generate executables

main_app.exe: main.c lib3tests.a
 $(XCC) $(XCFLAGS) main.c $(XLDFLAGS) -o main_app.exe

main_test.exe: main_app.exe
  $/bin/sparc-elf-objcopy --add-section .myelfsection=file.txt --change-section-address .myelfsection=0xcd000000 --set-section-flags .myelfsection=alloc,contents,load,data main_app.exe

main_app2.exe: main.c lib3tests.a
 $(XCC) $(XCFLAGS) main.c $(XLDFLAGS) -o main_app2.exe

apps: main_app2.exe main_test.exe
```

Many thanks

Comment: is the objcopy command ignored or is is it executed but behaves unexpectedly?

Comment: What is that `$` doing in front of `/bin/sparc-elf-objcopy ...`?

Comment: Schot: Sorry, I have a placeholder there, the line should read something like: $(GCC_DIRECTORY)/bin/sparc-elf-objcopy .... Alex: The objcopy line is completely ignored, so I do not get an error message or whatsover. Really weird

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a `TAB` character (not spaces) before `sparc-elf-objcopy` in this line:

```
main_test.exe: main_app.exe
    $/bin/sparc-elf-objcopy --add-section .myelfsection=file.txt --change-section-address .myelfsection=0xcd000000 --set-section-flags .myelfsection=alloc,contents,load,data main_app.exe
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but the result remains the same. Despite a TAB there, the sparc-elf-objcopy line is still ignored.

Comment: Then I get the error message: make: *** No rule to make target `main_app2.exe'.  Stop.

Comment: What about `make main_test.exe`??

Comment: the same error. That makes sense as my target is named "apps".

Comment: You **also** have a target named `main_test.exe`. It's weird. Can you put your `Makefile` somewhere to download it?

Comment: Sure, it can be downloaded from here, thanks for your help: http://www.4shared.com/file/0vyXl92m/Makefile-share.html

Answer (score 1):

Your sparc-elf-objcopy command seems to lack an output filename.

Have you tried reducing your makefile to triviality, with no inline variables or other expansions occurring?  I.e. Reduce it until make only calls your one line.

```
apps: main_app.exe
        sparc-elf-objcopy ... main_app.exe main_test.exe
```

Comment: should be main_app.exe at the end of the line. The thing is, this objcopy line works fine when entered directly in the shell, but is ignored for some reason in the Makefile

Comment: To be perhaps more explicit.  What is telling /bin/sparc-elf-objcopy to output to a file named main_test.exe ?